# Formassembly date format issue with salesforce connectors

Tags: data

I have a form built on formassembly with date field which accepts in a dd/mm/yyyy format.I have built custom validation for the date field so that it can only accept a date in dd/mm/yyyy.
While passing the values via the connector,it seems formassembly is treating it as mm/dd/yyyy.
The result a contact is created in salesforce
Please have a look at the screens shots.

form submitted via form assembly

[image: form input]

Contact created in SF:

[image: ui output]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: If your date format in FA is not the same format as SF you would see this issue. What happens in SF when you put a date of 30/04/2000 in the FA field? Do you get an error as an invalid date? FA send the literal value to SF and it is not converted to the SF format if it is different

Answer (score 0):

Under properties in your form builder, select English GB/Other under the language drop down.